# Semantic predicates fail but don't go to the next one

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I tried to use ANTLR4 to identify a range notation like `<1..100>`, and here is my attempt:

```
@parser::members {
def evalRange(self, minnum, maxnum, num):
    if minnum <= num <= maxnum:
        return True
    return False
}
range_1_100 : INT { self.evalRange(1, 100, $INT.int) }? ;
```

But it does not work for more than one range like:

```
some_rule : range_1_100 | range_200_300 ;
```

When I input a number (`200`), it just stops at the first rule:

```
200
line 3:0 rule range_1_100 failed predicate: { self.evalRange(1, 100, $INT.int) }?
(top (range_1_100 200))
```

It is not as I expected. How can I make the token match the next rule (`range_200_300`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from [the docs](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md) (emphasis mine):

> Predicates can appear anywhere within a parser rule just like actions can, but **only those appearing on the left edge of alternatives can affect prediction** (choosing between alternatives).
>
> *[...]*
>
> ANTLR's general decision-making strategy is to find all viable alternatives and then **ignore the alternatives guarded with predicates that currently evaluate to false**. (A viable alternative is one that matches the current input.) If more than one viable alternative remains, the parser chooses the alternative specified first in the decision.

Which basically means your predicate *must* be the first item in the alternation to be taken into account during the prediction phase.

Of course, you won't be able to use `$INT` as it wasn't matched yet at this point, but you can replace it with something like `_input.LA(1)` instead (lookahead of one token) - the exact syntax depends on your language target.

---

As a side note, I'd advise you to *not* validate the input through the grammar, it's easier and better to perform a separate validation pass *after* the parse. Let the grammar handle the syntax, not the semantics.

Comment: I understand, but it is hard to handle them after the parse. If there are two rules like: `some_rule2 : INT ; some_rule3 : INT ;`. They have different ranges, and it causes the ambiguous syntax. How can I overcome?

Comment: If you want to handle validation after the parse, use just one rule `range: INT;` and then handle the validation with a visitor - ANTLR generates the base classes for those. This way you eliminate the ambiguity and don't mix up syntax and semantics.

Comment: I tried visitor, but I have a big problem. While there is a rule accepts more than one range with different numeric ranges, the psudocode is like `more_than_one : range_1_10 range_20_30? range_40_50?`, and the real rule is `more_than_one : range+`. How can I distinguish those ranges in `visitMore_than_one()`?

Comment: `range+` yields a list of range contexts in the `more_than_one` context, just iterate over the list and perform your validation. You know the first one should be between 1 and 10, the second one between 20 and 30 and so on. If you still can't figure it out, post another question and make sure you include your visitor code.

Comment: The second one is not sure between 20 and 30, because the range_20_30 is optional and range_40_50 is, too. When the length of range list is 2, I can not sure what kind of range is.

Comment: Then see what's the number and accept it if it's between 20 and 30 *or* if it's between 40 and 50. I don't see where's the problem.